# How do I display specific rows in a column of data in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, scatter

I want to compare just SanFrancisco, Seattle, and Portland. The code below displays every region. `ax2.scatter(x=df['region']...`

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14,8))
ax1.scatter(x=df['AveragePrice'], y=df['Total Volume'])
ax2.scatter(x=df['region'], y=df['AveragePrice'])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to filter the rows?

Comment: `ax2.scatter(x=df.loc[df['region'].isin(['SanFrancisco', 'Seattle', 'Portland']), 'region'), y=df['AveragePrice'])`

Comment: I tried to simplify what I'm trying to do. So I changed the code to this and got an error message: "ValueError: x and y must be the same size."

# Let's just compare San Francisco, Seattle, and Portland's prices.

plt.scatter(x=df.loc[df['region'].isin(['SanFrancisco', 'Portland', 'Seattle'])], y=df['AveragePrice'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
ax1.scatter(x=df.loc[df['region'].isin(['SanFrancisco', 'Portland', 'Seattle']), 'region'), y=df['AveragePrice'])
```

You can find [more examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Don't forget to select the `'region'` column

Comment: plt.scatter(x=df.loc[df['region'].isin(['SanFrancisco', 'Portland', 'Seattle'])], y=df['AveragePrice']) 

ERROR: 'x and y must be the same size'